# Understanding routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-routes

I have trying to change the routing of my asp.net project. I want Login controller to load on startup of my project rather than any other controller. 
So, I have added LoginDefault routemap in existing routes in asp project

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "LoginDefault",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "UserManagement", action = "Login" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
```

This loads up the Login controller right but in doing so the default routing is not executed. After login, dashboard controller is invoked but "Index" is added to each URL as below.

http://localhost:49799/Dashboard/Index

This has effected my URL and other Ajax call and this doesn't look neat. Before adding the LoginDefault the URL would be

http://localhost:49799/Dashboard

I would like to achieve this. If any other way is possible that too will be fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
         name: "LoginDefault",
        url: "{controller}",
        defaults: new { controller = "UserManagement", action = "Login" }
    );
```

Comment: This route keep on rerouting to login controller instead of home controller even after correct login details is provided